# Angular no mantiene variable session en php

Tags: php, angular

Desde angular accedo al servidor php con httpclient, en el archivo php creo una variable de session  y me gustaría poder acceder ella  desde otra llamanda con Angular pero la variable me devuelve NUll

**Archivo A, Llamo al servidor desde ANgular**

```
postLogin(usuario: any,clave: any)//Metodo post
{ 
 this.usuario=usuario;
 this.clave=clave;

const headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

 var body:any = {
  "usuario":usuario,
  "clave":clave
  };


  this.httpclient.post(this.url, body ,{headers})
    .subscribe(
      (data:any)=>{
        if(data==1){
          this.display='none';
          this.router.navigate(['/principal']); 
        }
      }
    )
  }
}
```

Archivo php A

```
 <?php 
        header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-API-KEY, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Access-Control-Request-Method");
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE");
        @session_start();
    $_SESSION["token"]="Hola"; **//Variable de session que quiero que guarde**
?>
```

Entiendo que así, tengo la variable de session guardada y podría acceder a ella, pero cuando desde angular hago otra llamada con httpclient al servidor ( A otro archivo)  y hago un echo de de la variable de session creada anteriormente, esta me da null. Si accedo directamente al primer archivo desde el navegador ("El que crea la session) y después desde el navegador accedo al segundo archivo (El que lee la variable) Si veo la variable. Cuando pongo el proyecto en producción, si me funcionan las session.